# How do I read the value of context menu checkbox?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that a user might want to frequently enable/disable. To facilitate this, I'd like to add a checkbox to the context menu that basically says "extension enabled". When a page loads, it would check to see if there was a check by the context menu item. I have created the menu item, and it stays persistent throughout page loads, but I don't know how to read its value. Can anyone help me out?

Here is the code that I'm using to add the checkbox to the context menu.

```
var checkbox1 = chrome.contextMenus.create({
    "title": "Enable",
    "type": "checkbox",
    "onclick":enableAutofilter
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Chrome docs, it appears that there is no way to read information about a context menu item.  There are `create`, `update`, and `remove` functions, but no `read` function (so it has only three of the [CRUD](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operators).  This means that you'll have to maintain the on/off state elsewhere, e.g., on your background page and/or in localStorage, and toggle it when you fire `enableAutoFilter`.